# Function composition with functor - Performance overhead

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, lambda, functor

As we know, in C++ 11, can't deduce the return type of function returning lambda with `auto` or `decltype(auto)`. So can't use code like below.

```cpp
template <typename F, typename G>
constexpr decltype(auto) compose(const F& f, const G& g) noexcept 
{
    return [&f,&g](auto&& x)
    {
        return f(g(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)));
    };
}
```

Instead, work around like the below could be employed;

```cpp
template <typename F, typename G>
struct Composed
{
    const F &f;
    const G &g;

    Composed(const F &f, const G &g) : f(f), g(g) {}

    template <typename Arg>
    inline auto operator()(Arg &&arg) -> decltype(f(g(std::forward<Arg>(arg))))
    {
        return f(g(std::forward<Arg>(arg)));
    }
};

template <typename F, typename G>
Composed<F, G> compose(const F &f, const G &g)
{
    return Composed<F, G>(f, g);
}
```

As always, the actual performance could vary by time, but what would be the general performance of this approach compared to lambda capturing lambda?

Does adding `inline` in front of `operator()` could help? Or still there is inevitable overhead?

Comment: How about use the same compiler with C++17 and C++11 on both ways in assembly separately?

Comment: Measure the overhead with your compiler on your OS.

Comment: Prior to measuring performance, you should ensure correctness. Both code snippets may store references to temporaries.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit Well, to say, this is for portable library, so can't sure the act of platform specific compiler's act. Would it be generally equivalent if considering common mechanism of C++ and disregarding platform specific minor difference?

Comment: @user7860670 You are right. Thank you for the comment. Will fix the code.

Comment: Both code snippets may still store references to temporaries. Typically a viable approach in such a situation is to keep using universal reference and to add a `static_assert` checking that type is not an rvalue reference.

Comment: So measure it on multiple platforms, no biggie.C++ is an abstract specification, it doesn't address performance (only asymptotic complexity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always benchmark your code, where you get the illusion that one is more run-time/compile-time/memory/space efficient over the other. For instance, using the tool from quick-bench.com, both codes without storing the references, for function pointers `f<std::string>`, `g<std::string>` I get the following <sup>*</sup>result.

https://quick-bench.com/q/ZbgOBnT7Or1EJqXlSF-LHf4b8l0

[image]

**<sup>*</sup>Warning** : I might be wrong, in assuming the parameters of the functions that passed; however you may play around with different code changes, compilers and optimization options, and see if one way is better than the other.

Comment: Change arguments in compose17 to values and make the function static (easily inline'able) and the results will  be way closer:
https://quick-bench.com/q/rf5N9yMsdeFCP5497fOJJ1133ys

Comment: Sure. My point was more about the semantics used, which were not entirely equivalent. But granted, measuring without context does not make a lot of sense anyway.